# AWS / iOS / Cognito: unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the **[S3TransferUtilitySampleObjC](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtility-Sample/Objective-C)** project to work with my **Cognito** and AWS credentials.

Unfortunately I am getting the error below:

```
AWSURLSessionManager.m line:566 | -[AWSURLSessionManager printHTTPHeadersForResponse:] | Response headers:
{
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 111;
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
    Date = "Mon, 16 Jan 2017 17:17:50 GMT";
    "x-amzn-ErrorMessage" = "Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.";
    "x-amzn-ErrorType" = "NotAuthorizedException:";
    "x-amzn-RequestId" = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx";
}
```

Would you be able to help?

---

**Code (note that I only removed some code from the SecondViewController and modified the values in Constants - I also modified the Info.plist file (see screenshot below)**

I am currently focusing only on **downloading the file** from my S3 bucket.
Hence I modified only the following:

```
// In Constants.m
NSString *const S3BucketName = @"mybucketname";
NSString *const S3DownloadKeyName = @"config.plist";

// In SecondViewController.m

#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
#import "Constants.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;

@property (copy, nonatomic) AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock completionHandler;
@property (copy, nonatomic) AWSS3TransferUtilityProgressBlock progressBlock;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.progressView.progress = 0;
    self.statusLabel.text = @"Ready";

    __weak SecondViewController *weakSelf = self;
    self.completionHandler = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask *task, NSURL *location, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (error) {
                weakSelf.statusLabel.text = @"Failed to Download";
            }
            if (data) {
                weakSelf.statusLabel.text = @"Successfully Downloaded";
                weakSelf.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                weakSelf.progressView.progress = 1.0;
            }
        });
    };

    self.progressBlock = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityTask *task, NSProgress *progress) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            weakSelf.progressView.progress = progress.fractionCompleted;
        });
    };

    AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];
    [transferUtility enumerateToAssignBlocksForUploadTask:nil downloadTask:^(AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask * _Nonnull downloadTask, AWSS3TransferUtilityProgressBlock  _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable downloadProgressBlockReference, AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock  _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable completionHandlerReference) {
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)downloadTask.taskIdentifier);

        *downloadProgressBlockReference = weakSelf.progressBlock;
        *completionHandlerReference = weakSelf.completionHandler;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.statusLabel.text = @"Uploading...";
        });
    }];
}

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    self.imageView.image = nil;

    AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression *expression = [AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression new];
    expression.progressBlock = self.progressBlock;

    AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];
    [[transferUtility downloadDataFromBucket:S3BucketName
                                         key:S3DownloadKeyName
                                  expression:expression
                            completionHander:self.completionHandler] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        }
        if (task.exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", task.exception);
        }
        if (task.result) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.statusLabel.text = @"Downloading...";
            });
        }

        return nil;
    }];
}
```

**Info.plist** file modified at:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is explaining the issue - you're sending a request to Cognito as an unauthenticated user, meaning no logins are included/linked to that identity, while it isn't enabled for the pool.

Unauthenticated identities are an opt in feature for an identity pool, you have to enable it while creating/editing your pool from the Cognito console.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I will ask the DB admin to enabled this. Alternatively, how do you authenticate a Cognito user? We have created a test user in the federate identity. Sorry for the lame question, just trying to get the first steps on this.

Comment: Oh, no worries! Authenticated users just refer to users who have signed in to some identity provider that is also configured for the pool (i.e. Facebook, Google, Twitter, or a linked User Pool). What you might set up depends on your application's needs, but there's samples that can show you how to use various providers: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoSync-Sample

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the link. I think I may ask to disable the feature. So basically the point to support a third party provider is to increase security. The app I am developing is for internal use only so I may not need that for the first version. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: Sure, in that case unauthenticated makes sense as a way to go. You're right, it's a security thing. A common case is to give unauthenticated users low rights, then increase what they can do when they sign in. Think of it as guest access. With what you're doing, though, that doesn't make as much sense, so going just unauth makes sense.

Comment: my aws admin said that they can't disable the unauthenticated identities. However, when I look up on the AWS documentation I get a bit lost and can't find an example that is relevant to me (most of the ones I find refer to the identity pool id and not to an identity in the format username + password). Would you be able to point me towards the right direction? The AWS admin created a username for me to use, however I don't really know where to put these credentials. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html